# PHP array optimization for 80k rows

Tags: php, arrays

I need help to find workaround for getting over memory_limit. My limit is 128MB, from database I'm getting something about 80k rows, script stops at 66k. Thanks for help.

Code:

```
$posibilities = [];
    foreach ($result as $item) {
            $domainWord = str_replace("." . $item->tld, "", $item->address);

            for ($i = 0; $i + 2 < strlen($domainWord); $i++) {
                $tri = $domainWord[$i] . $domainWord[$i + 1] . $domainWord[$i + 2];


                if (array_key_exists($tri, $possibilities)) {
                    $possibilities[$tri] += 1;
                } else {
                    $possibilities[$tri] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pure math tells us that you have about 1.6kb per record with those memory limits, minus some overhead for array data structures and stuff already in memory. What kind of data are you trying to store, how large is each record? You're also doing a bunch of string operations which will cause more data to clutter up the available memory. We can't tell you how to optimise that based on the tiny speck of information given.

Comment: A trivial solution, if what you describe is correct, to split the job into parts, for example by limiting the number of results from the database.

Comment: avoid string manipulation in this PHP.  try doing it all in sql to cut down on memory

Comment: if the operation is safe, you could `exec` or `shell_exec` and use OS string manipulation commands like `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bottleneck, given your algorithm, is most possibly not the database query, but the `$possibilities` array you're building.

If I read your code correctly, you get a list of domain names from the database. From each of the domain names you strip off the top-level-domain at the end first.

Then you walk character-by-character from left to right of the resulting string and collect triplets of the characters from that string, like this:

`example.com` => `['exa', 'xam', 'amp', 'mpl', 'ple']`

You store those triplets in the `keys` of the array, which is nice idea, and you also count them, which doesn't have any effect on the memory consumption. However, my guess is that the sheer number of possible triplets, which is for 26 letters and 10 digits is 36^3 = 46656 possibilities each taking 3 bytes just for *key* inside array, don't know how many boilerplate code around it, take quite a lot from your memory limit.

Probably someone will tell you how PHP uses memory with its database cursors, I don't know it, but you can do one trick to profile your memory consumption.

Put the calls to [`memory-get-usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php):

- before and after each iteration, so you'll know how many memory was wasted on each cursor advancement,
- before and after each addition to `$possibilities`.

And just print them right away. So you'll be able to run your code and see in real time what and how seriously uses your memory.

Also, try to `unset` the `$item` after each iteration. It may actually help.

Knowledge of specific database access library you are using to obtain `$result` iterator will help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Given the tiny (pretty useless) code snippet you've provided I want to provide you with a MySQL answer, but I'm not certain you're using MySQL?

But
- Optimise your table.

- Use `EXPLAIN` to optimise your query. Rewrite your query to put as much of the logic in the query rather than in the PHP code. 
  edit: if you're using MySQL then prepend `EXPLAIN` before your `SELECT` keyword and the result will show you an explanation of actually how the query you give MySQL turns into results.
- Do not use PHP `strlen` function as this is memory inefficient - instead you can compare by treating a string as a set of array values, thus:

  `for ($i = 0; !empty($domainWord[$i+2]); $i++) {`
- in your MySQL (if that's what you're using) then add a `LIMIT` clause that will break the query into 3 or 4 chunks, say of 25k rows per chunk, which will fit comfortably into your maximum operating capacity of 66k rows. Burki had this good idea.

At the end of each chunk clean all the strings and restart, set into a loop

```
$z = 0;
 while ($z < 4){
///do grab of data from database. Preserve only your output 
$z++;
}
```

---

But probably more important than any of these is provide enough details in your question!! 
- What is the data you want to get?
- What are you storing your data in?
- What are the criteria for finding the data?

These answers will help people far more knowledgable than me to show you how to properly optimise your database.